# (transform.position C#) Simple command, unexpected response

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am trying to build a free roam camera for film making in unity. This is mainly to learn the fundamentals of C# scripting.

```
if(Input.GetButton("Vertical"))
{transform.position = Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;}
```

Now when i run the function in Update after placing the script on a gameobject with the camera. The camera fails to move beyond 0.07 on the Z axis. The number varies while the game is running, which means the script is working. But i fail to understand why is it not moving beyond a point in game engines world space. I am confused if it is something with unity engine or visual studio.

Comment: Replace "transform.position=" with "transform.position+=".

Answer (score 3):

It is because you are **setting** the position to a value instead of **adding** the value to the current position.

Try this:

```
if(Input.GetButton("Vertical"))
{
    transform.position = transform.position + Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

(And not the code formating. Use backlines to seperate each `{` and `}`, it is more readable and a good practice)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime)
```